# Need suggestion for linking accounts from different sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

Currently I am working on rails 4 project, and now I have to link / connect another application (not so).

Say, I have a link as 'Connect to example.com' and when user clicks on the link it will open the sign in page of example.com.

After entering credentials, it will redirect from example.com to my site.

As per my understanding I have to use Oauth.

So can any explain the approach for implementing this?

Thnaks

Comment: You can use **omniauth Gem** use follow this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084864/how-to-use-omniauth-only-for-authorization-from-different-apis-without-authentic/37085275#37085275

Comment: You can use **omniauth Gem** use follow this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084864/how-to-use-omniauth-only-for-authorization-from-different-apis-without-authentic/37085275#37085275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Gem Domp https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/domp 
It provides omniauth authentication for many platforms. There is a complete list of authentications it provides on this page:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies

Comment: so I have to implement omiauth strategy, please confirm?

Comment: Just follow the process mentioned in the docs. Add this gem and the provider(strategy) you want to use. For example you want to add facebook then you will add domp gem , omniauth and omniauth-facebook gems. Follow the rest of process mentioned in docs.